# How to correctly implement boundary conditions with Chebyshev differentiation matrix?

Tags: boundary-conditions, fourier-analysis, spectral-method, collocation, chebyshev

In my code I am able to implement zero Dirichlet boundary conditions, however, in my opinion my method does not seem to be as smooth and effective as possible. I am solving a Poisson's equation with two different boundary conditions, periodic along x and non-periodic (zero Dirichlet) along y. Therefore, my I have to be careful when building my Laplacian. For the example code I provided, I am including an operator `ZNy` which represents the operation of setting the boundary values of y component to zero. Then, additionally to this I am enforcing the BCs inside my iterative solver at every iteration.

The Poisson's equation:
$$
\nabla \cdot (n\nabla u) = S
$$
or can be expanded as: $n \nabla^2 u + \nabla u \cdot \nabla n = S$

where BCs are periodic in x and zero Dirichlet in y as $u(x,a)=0$ & $u(x,b)=0$.

The code example:

```
Nx = 4*16; 
Ny = 4*16; 
Lx =2*16;
kx  = fftshift(-Nx/2:Nx/2-1); % wave number vector
dx = Lx/Nx; 
% Use approximations for kx, and k^2. These come from Birdsall and Langdon
ksqu = (sin( kx * dx/2)/(dx/2)).^2 ;
kx = sin(kx * dx) / dx;
ksqu4inv = ksqu; 
ksqu4inv(abs(ksqu4inv)<1e-14) =1; %helps with error: matrix ill scaled because of 0s
xi_x =  2*pi/Lx;
xi  = (0:Nx-1)/Nx*2*pi;
x =  xi/xi_x;

ylow = 0;  %a
yupp =16;  %b
Ly = (yupp-ylow);
eta_ygl  = 2/Ly;
[D,etagl] = cheb(Ny);
% rescaling my Chebyshev Differentiation Matrices to an arbitrary domain [a,b] by performing a change of variables as the following:
ygl = (1/2)*((yupp-ylow)*etagl + (yupp+ylow));
D   = D*eta_ygl;
D2  = D*D;
[X,Y]   = meshgrid(x,ygl);

Igl = speye(Ny+1);
%ZNy represents the operation of setting the boundary values of y component
%to zero:
ZNy = diag([0 ones(1,Ny-1) 0]); %diag([0 ones(1,Ny-1) 0]); 
div_y_act_on_grad_y = D2* ZNy; 
%ICs
A = 2*pi / Lx;
u = (Y-ylow) .* (Y-yupp) .* sin( (A) * X);
uh = fft(u,[],2);

n = (eta_ygl)*(Y-((ylow+yupp)/2)).^2 .* sin( (3 * A) * X)+ 10;
invnek = fft(1./n,[],2);
nh = fft(n,[],2);
dnhdxk = (kx*1i*xi_x).*nh;
dnhdyk =D * nh;

%Exact source 
 ExactSource = (1/(2*(ylow - yupp)))*((-2 + ylow*A^2 *(yupp - Y) + A^2 .*Y .*(-yupp + Y)) .*sin(A*X) .*(20*(-ylow + yupp) + (ylow + yupp - 2*Y).^2 .* sin(3*A*X)) - (ylow + yupp - 2*Y).^2 .*(3*A^2 *(ylow - Y) .* (yupp - Y) .* cos(A *X).^2 .* (-1 + 2*cos(2*A*X)) + 4*sin(A*X) .*sin(3*A*X)));

oldSol = ones(size(u));
oldSolk = fft(oldSol ,[],2);
err_max =1e-4;
max_iter = 500;
Sourcek = fft(ExactSource,[],2); 
for iterations = 1:max_iter
    oldSolMax = max(max(abs(oldSolk)));
    dudxk = (kx*1i*xi_x) .*oldSolk;
    %product:
    gradNgradUx = aapx(dnhdxk,dudxk);
    dudyk = (D) *oldSolk ; 
    gradNgradUy = aapx(dnhdyk,dudyk); 
    %RHS of PDE
    RHSk = Sourcek - (gradNgradUx + gradNgradUy); 
    Stilde = aapx(invnek,RHSk);
    for m = 1:length(kx)
        L = -Igl * (ksqu4inv(m))*xi_x^2+ div_y_act_on_grad_y;
        newSolk(:,m) = L\(Stilde(:,m));

    end
        %enforce BCs    
        newSolk=[zeros(1,Nx);  newSolk(2:Ny,:); zeros(1,Nx)];
    
    newSolMax = max(max(abs(newSolk)));
    if newSolMax < err_max 
        it_error = err_max /2;
    else
        it_error = abs( newSolMax - oldSolMax ) / newSolMax ;
    end
    if it_error < err_max
        break;
    end
    oldSolk = newSolk;
 
end
```

`Cheb(N)` function is taken from Spectral Methods textbook and can be found: [HERE][4]

```
% CHEB compute D = differentitation matrix, x = Chebyshev grid
function [D, x] = cheb(N)
  if N == 0, D = 0; x = 1; return, end
  x = cos(pi*(0:N)/N)';
  c = [2; ones(N-1,1); 2].*(-1).^(0:N)';
  X = repmat(x,1,N+1);
  dX = X-X';
  D = (c*(1./c)')./(dX+(eye(N+1)));
  D = D - diag(sum(D'));
```

and `aapx` is a function deals with aliasing errors:

```
function ph=aapx(uh,vh) %anti-aliased product, 
% in: uh,vh from fft with n samples
%use discrete transform with m rather than n points, where m >= 3N/2
[ny nx]=size(uh);m=nx*3/2;
uhp=[uh(:,1:nx/2) zeros(ny,(m-nx)) uh(:,nx/2+1:nx)]; % pad uhat with zeros
vhp=[vh(:,1:nx/2) zeros(ny,(m-nx)) vh(:,nx/2+1:nx)]; % pad vhat with zeros
up=ifft(uhp,[],2); 
vp=ifft(vhp,[],2); 
w=up.*vp; 
wh=fft(w,[],2);
ph=1.5*[wh(:,1:nx/2) wh(:,m-nx/2+1:m)]; % extract F-coefficients
```

Basically, is there a simpler way to implement the zero Dirichlet boundary conditions in my Chebyshev differentiation matrix?

Also, I found a similar code example from the Spectral Methods textbook that uses Mixed Chebyshev/Fourier method for a 2D wave equation where they implement their boundary conditions differently, but I am unable to get it to work for my above code unfortunately:

````
clearvars; clc; close all;
 %2D wave equation with split method from prgram 37.m in textbook.
 %Homogeneous Neumann BCs along y and periodic along x
 
 %the Neumann BCs are essentially imposed as in Program 33: 
 %x variable in [-A,A], Fourier 
 A=3; Nx=50; dx =2*A/Nx; x= -A+dx*(1:Nx)';
 D2x = (pi/A)^2*toeplitz([-1/(3*(dx/A)^2)-1/6 ...
     0.5*(-1).^(2:Nx)./sin((pi*dx/A)*(1:Nx-1)/2).^2]);
 %y variable in [-1,1], chebyshev:
 Ny=15; 
[Dy,y] = cheb(Ny);
D2y=Dy^2;
 BC=-Dy([1 Ny+1],[1 Ny+1])\Dy([1 Ny+1],2:Ny); %Homogenous Neumann BCs for |y|=1 
 
 %Grid and initial data:
 
 [xx,yy] = meshgrid(x,y);
 %ICs are chosen as:
 % vv represnts ICs of u(x,y,t=0):
 vv=exp(-8*((xx+1.5).^2 + yy.^2));
 dt = 5/(Nx+Ny^2);
 % vvold represnts ICs of u(x,y,t=-dt)= exp(-8*((xx+dt+1.5).^2 + yy.^2)); :
 %this can be written as ut(x,y,0)=-ux(x,y,0)
 vvold = exp(-8*((xx+dt+1.5).^2+yy.^2));
 %Time stepping by leap frog forula:
  dt = 5/(Nx+Ny^2);clf; plotgap=round(2/dt); dt=2/plotgap;
 for n=0:2*plotgap
     t=n*dt;
     if rem(n+.5,plotgap)<1
         subplot(3,1,n/plotgap+1), mesh(xx,yy,vv), view(-10,60)
         colormap([0 0 0])
         text(-2.5,1,.5,['t=' num2str(t)],'fontsize',18),,grid off, drawnow
     end
     vvnew= 2*vv - vvold + dt^2*(vv*D2x+D2y*vv);
     vvold = vv; vv = vvnew;
     vv([1 Ny+1],:) = BC*vv(2:Ny,:); %Neumann BCs for |y|=1
 end
```
````